# Facebook post on news feed and link behind the "name" of the post

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am posting a post on the current user feed with the following code:

```
   NSMutableDictionary *postParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"http://url.com/image.jpg", @"picture",
                                   @"The title of the post on the feed", @"name",
                                   @"Caption text", @"caption",
                                   @"Description text", @"description", nil];

   [self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:postParams andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:nil];
```

It works great but I can't figure out how to setup the link behind the name of the post ("The title of the post on the feed"). For now the link looks like the following :

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=[MY_APP_ID]&method=permissions.request&redirect_uri=[THE_URL_OF_THE_PICTURE]&response_type=code&display=page&auth_referral=1
```

Is there a way to control this url easily? Thanks!

-- EDIT --

Here is a screenshot of a kind of post I want to create : 
[image]

http://cl.ly/image/020D1z3S2L16.
The link behind the blue title "Je t'ai envoyé un défi dans Années 80" is really clean (just like http://itunes.apple.com/app/[APP_NAME]) and I'd like to do the same.

I believe this not an open graph action, just a basic post. Thanks

Comment: add a parameter named `@"link"` to your NSMutableDictionary...

Comment: Already tried, but the post is turning himself into a "Martin shared a link". I don't want it this way. I already saw people doing that so I'm trying too :)

Comment: Could you please specify what it actually is your trying to achieve a little more, screenshot perhaps? I think you might be talking about some Open Graph actions here actually, and not just a posted link.

Comment: @CBroe - I just edited the post with a screenshot and more details

Comment: Whenever you post a feed using Graph API, you are always "sharing a link". The way it is displayed on any user's feed is controlled by Facebook. I have had similar situation where I made a feed as a page. The way this feed was displayed on users home was different. Some users saw the complete post, but some got "xyz shared a link". You cannot control it.

Comment: No it is different, if you omit the @"link" parameter then the post will display how the @MartinMoizard wants. When the @"link" is added the "Shared a link" type of post is displayed. Unfortunately when an image is include via the @"picture" then the title of the post is linked to that image url which is not the desired effect. Hope anyone stumbles upon this and helps us out

Comment: Thanks Fotis Paraskevopoulos :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"xx shared a link" cannot be controlled through a post. Facebook is performing tons of A/B testing to decide what to display...

Answer (score 2):

All parameters of the Facebook feed are outlined in the Graph API reference, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/.

The relevant ones are "name", "caption", "description" or "message". Therefore, if whatever is the element you are referring to is not affected, you don't have control over it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of this page but I'm asking the question because I see on Facebook posts with a clean url behind the name of the post so I'm trying to do the same but can't find how.

Answer (score 2):

Hey Its very easy just try this code.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary] ;
    [params setObject:@"Test post" forKey:@"message"];
    [params setObject:@"link" forKey:@"type"];
    [params setObject:@"http://yoursite.com" forKey:@"link"];
    [params setObject:@"Link description" forKey:@"description"];


    // Make the request
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                              if (!error) {

                                  if(appDelegate.isLoggedInWithTwitter)
                                  {
                                      [self postMessage:_lblTitle.text];
                                  }
                                  else
                                  {
                                      [self toggleProgressHud:NO title:@"" message:@""];
                                      NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"result: %@", result]);
                                      UIAlertView *alertMsg=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Shared Successfully" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
                                      alertMsg.tag=11;
                                      alertMsg.delegate=self;
                                      [alertMsg show];
                                  }
                                  // Link posted successfully to Facebook
                              } else {
                                  // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                  // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                  NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", error.description]);
                                  [self toggleProgressHud:NO title:@"" message:@""];
                                  [self handleAPICallError:error];
                              }
                          }];
```

And here is the result which you want

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> For now the link looks like the following :
>
> `https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=…&method=permissions.request&…`

That sounds like you’ve got Authenticated Referrals enabled in your app settings …?

That would explain, why the link points to the Facebook URL with a parameter `method=permissions.request` embedded.

If so, and that’s not what you want – then turn of Authenticated Referrals.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this

Comment: When I'm trying it turning off Authenticated Referrals, the link is equal to http://url.com/image.jpg :(

Comment: Well, that’s the only URL value you posted, so what kind of different behavior did you expect? If you want to post a link to an actual website instead of just an image) – then post the website URL as a `link` parameter; and set up this page to have appropriate Open Graph meta tags, if you desire Facebook to scrape info from it automatically.